# How to escape single quote in Vim

Tags: vimscript, external-command

I have this mapping in my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>vlc :exe "!open -a vlc '".getline('.')."'"<CR>
```

It does work great with some files, but I'm getting error message with files that have single quote in it:

> /Users/dude/Downloads/check/39min tpope's Vim Config and
> Plugins-MGmIJyTf8pg.mp4

The error message:

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>
> /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>
> shell returned 2
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than add quotes yourself, use the [`shellescape()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) function, which should take care or all edge cases:

```
:nnoremap <silent><leader>vlc :exe "!open -a vlc " . shellescape(getline('.'))<CR>
```

Another way is to use the [`%:S`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%25%3aS) filename modifier:

```
:echo fnamemodify("Hello 'world", '')
Hello 'world

:echo fnamemodify("Hello 'world", ':S')
'Hello '\''world'

:echo expand('%')
hello 'world

:echo expand('%:S')
'hello '\''world'
```

In this particular case `shellescape()` probably makes more sense, but `:S` is useful especially when you want to combine it with other filename modifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome help. It does work perfectly ^^

Comment: Don't you also need `fnameescape()`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks, I think you may be right and that this answer is wrong >_< No time to update it right now.

Comment: This is more involved than it looks.  You'd think that `fnameescape(shellescape(...))` does the trick, but it doesn't.  On UNIX you need _at least_ something like this: `escape(fnameescape(shellescape(...)), '&()')`, but of course that won't work on Windows (I don't know the answer for Windows).  This has to do with the way `:!` is implemented, and is the reason why `syntastic` switched from `makeprg` and friends to `system()` and `lgetexpr`.  I'd be surprised if you could find a solution that actually works everywhere, across all sets of characters. :)